# Find probability that a vehicle requiring $2$ adjacent spaces can be parked

Tags: combinatorics

> In a parking lot there are $16$ slots adjacent to each other in a row.$12$ drivers along with their cars enter the parking lot and park their cars in $12$ of the $16$ slots available at random.Uncle Sam enters the parking lot in his mini truck which requires $2$ adjacent slots to park.What is the probability that Uncle Sam will be able to park his car?

My Attempt:I am confused about finding total number of ways in which 14 slots can be occupied. The given answer is $\frac{17}{28}$

Comment: Total number of ways is: $\binom{16}{12}=\binom{16}{4}$ to park $12$ cars in this $16$ slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be $4$ open slots, which are equally likely to be any of the ${16 \choose 4} = 1820$ possible choices of $4$ slots out of $16$.
The number of ways to choose 4 open slots so that Sam can't park (because no two are adjacent) is ${13 \choose 4} = 715$.  That is, every choice of four distinct elements $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$ from $\{1,2,\ldots, 13\}$
corresponds to the open slots $x_1$, $x_2+1$, $x_3+2$, $x_4+3$.
The probability that Sam can't park is then $715/1820 = 11/28$, and the probability that he can park is $1 - 11/28 = 17/28$.

Answer (score 2):

First, notice there are $\binom{16}{12} = \binom{16}{4}$ ways to park the 12 cars in the 16 slots.  You can think about an event in this sample space as a string of 16 ones and zeroes, where 1 means a car is parked in that slot, and 0 means there is none.  How many strings that are 16 long and have four 0's in them have at least one 00 in them?

It's easier to count the opposite: how many such strings *do not* have 00 in them?  Either the last digit is a 1 or a 0.  We can form all strings that do not have 00 in them and end in 1 by shuffling eight 1's and four 01's.  There are $\binom{12}{4}$ ways to do this.  We can form all strings that do not have 00 in them and end in zero by shuffling nine 1's and three 01's, and adding 0 at the very end.  There are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to do this.  So the probability that the truck *cannot* park is
$$
    \frac{\binom{12}{4} + \binom{12}{3}}{\binom{16}{4}} = \frac{11}{28}
$$